# Setting column headings on report export

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using the following blog post to help me export a report. It works great however i wondered is it possible to set column heading names?

http://spendolini.blogspot.co.uk/2006/04/custom-export-to-csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to provide an initial row with column headers in it:

```
begin
   -- Set the MIME type
   owa_util.mime_header( 'application/octet', FALSE );
   -- Set the name of the file
   htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="emp.csv"');
   -- Close the HTTP Header
   owa_util.http_header_close;
   -- Send the initial row with headers
   htp.prn('Ename,Empno,Department'||chr(13));
   -- Loop through all rows in EMP
   for x in (select e.ename, e.empno, d.dname
             from emp e, dept d where e.deptno = d.deptno
             and e.deptno like :P1_DEPTNO)
   loop 
   -- Print out a portion of a row, 
   -- separated by commas and ended by a CR
   htp.prn(x.ename ||','|| x.empno ||','||
            x.dname || chr(13));
   end loop;
   -- Send an error code so that the
   -- rest of the HTML does not render
   --htmldb_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
   --use stop apex_engine 
   apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
end;
```

Basically you just emit one extra row before you emit the data rows.

I commented `htmldb_application` in favor of `apex_application.stop_apex_engine`. [See documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_app.htm#BABGIDII)

Comment: I just copy pasted the code an ran it, it gave me the csv with the extra row. Not sure how you got the one row all split out. Did you change out the commas if you changed them for the data rows? When do you get the extra rows: when you downloaded the file or once you've split the text?

Comment: Its because i hit return at the end of each column name, ive done it as above now and works great. Thank you :-)